# datatable server all data show in first page, side rendering pagination problem

Tags: node.js, express, datatable

I am trying to render via siderendering because of the query load quite long and it
crash my browser, but it comes with another problem

Result is okay
it show Showing 1 to 10 of 354 entries
and pagination is correct , the problem is all 354 entries all showed in first page
even I click 2nd or 3rd page still showing all.

my nodejs server

```
router.post('/:id/testDepositTable', function (req, res, next) {
    const draw = req.body.draw || 1; // Echo back the 'draw' parameter

    // Your SQL query
    const query = `
    SELECT DISTINCT transaction.*, bonus_used.bonus_name, bonus_used.multiply, DATE(transaction.date) AS transaction_date
    FROM bonus_used, transaction
    WHERE transaction.customer = ?
    AND bonus_used.bonus_name = transaction.cashbonus
    ORDER BY transaction.trans_id;
    `;

    db.query(query, [req.params.id], function (err, testDeposit, field) {
        if (err) {
            // Handle the error, for example:
            console.error('Database error:', err);
            res.json({ error: 'Database error' });
        } else {
            const totalNumberOfRecords = testDeposit.length;
            const filteredNumberOfRecords = totalNumberOfRecords;

            const ret = {
                code: 200,
                msg: 'success',
                draw: draw,
                recordsTotal: totalNumberOfRecords,
                recordsFiltered: filteredNumberOfRecords,
                data: testDeposit,
            };
            res.json(ret);
        }
    });
});
```

table html

```
<table id="test_deposit_table" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
                        <thead class="bg-light">
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>Ref</th>
                                <th>Date & Time</th>
                                <th>Member</th>
                                <th>Product</th>
                                <th>Bank</th>
                                <th>Amount</th>
                                <th>Bonus Amount</th>
                                <th>TurnOver</th>
                                <th>Promo</th>
                                <th>Status</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
```

JS

```
  $('#test_deposit_table').DataTable({
                    "processing": true,
                    "serverSide": true,
                    "bServerSide":true,
                    "ajax": {
                        "url": window.location.href.split('/').pop() + "/testDepositTable",
                        "type": "post",
                        "data": function (d) {
                            console.log(d)
                            d.start = d.start || 0;  // Set a default value if not provided
                            d.length = d.length || 25;  // Set a default value if not provided
                            // You can add more custom parameters if needed
                            // d.xxx = "xxx";
                        }
                    },
                    "lengthMenu": [10, 25, 50],
                    "paging": true, // Specify the available page lengths
                    "columns": [
                        { data: 'trans_id' },
                        { data: null },
                        { data: 'date' },
                        { data: null },
                        { data: 'products' },
                        { data: 'bank' },
                        { data: 'amount' },
                        { data: 'bonus_amount' },
                        { data: null },
                        { data: 'cashbonus' },
                        { data: 'status' },
                    ],
                    "columnDefs": [{

                        "targets": -1,
                        "data": null
                    }],
                    "createdRow": function (row, data, dataIndex) {
                        var amount = parseFloat(data.amount);
                        var bonusAmount = parseFloat(data.bonus_amount);
                        var multiply = parseFloat(data.multiply);
                        var DPref = "DP" + moment(data.date).format('YMMDD') + data.trans_id
                        var turnover = amount + (bonusAmount * multiply);
                        $('td:eq(1)', row).html("DP" + data.date);
                        $('td:eq(3)', row).html(`MS${data.customer}`);
                        $('td:eq(8)', row).html(turnover);
                    }
                });
```